# Как парсить сайт после отработки всех скриптов на нем?

Tags: java, html, парсер

Возникла вот такая проблема. Есть сайт на котом после загрузки и отработки всех скриптов значение записывается в блок div. Пробовал парсить Jsoup, но я так понял он не видит эти значение, точнее не может их подгрузить.

Подскажите какие есть технологии и если можна пару примеров

Comment: вам нужен эмулятор браузер а-ля selenium

Comment: Подскажите как его использовать. Пробовал selenium,  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); но возвращает NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap

Comment: JaroslavKhahyda, чтобы решить ошибку: `NoCalssDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap`,  очистите и пересоберите ваш проект, проверьте путь к классам, проверьте различные версии библиотек, которые могут там быть. Если вы используете какую-то систему управления зависимостями (Maven, Ivy и т. д.), убедитесь, что она настроена правильно.

Comment: Если добавляли без сборщика вручную, то проверьте не добавляли ли вы `selenium-java-2.25.0.jar` и попробуйте заменить на `selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar`, который включает в себя все необходимые файлы.

Comment: Помогло. Запустилось. Ему еще для работы не хватало geckodriver.exe

Comment: А можно как-то сделать, чтобы запускался в консольном браузере? Чтобы не было видно запуска firefox

Comment: JaroslavKhahyda, лично не пробовал, но как вариант может поможет [devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253973/8370915) по аналогии с хромом.

Comment: Вы немного не правильно меня поняли. Не саму консоль браузера нужно запустить. А нужно чтобы браузер запускался без оконного режима. А то когда работает парсер, постоянно запускается firefox и потом сама же закрывается. Можно как-то сделать чтобы было невидно пользователю запуск firefox?

Comment: @JaroslavKhahyda, наверное, вам нужно что-то типа `GhostDriver`

Comment: А можно подробней об этом? Или ссылку на пример